# How do i make multiple conditions in java?

Tags: java

Write a program that does the following:
The program uses the Scanner object to ask the user for input of a whole number (integer).
If the user enters a whole number greater than or equal to 10 but less than 20, the program calculates the value of 10 raised to the power of the number entered and outputs that value, otherwise if the user enters a number greater or equal to zero but less than 10 the program calculates the product of 100 times the number entered and outputs that result. If the user enters the number -1 the program exits without providing an output. All other numbers entered are indicated as invalid entry numbers via an output statement stating so. 
Input is received from user via the scanner object (from the keyboard) only once (no loop is needed in this program).  Make sure that you output a statement first indicating to the user to enter whole numbers only. 
Compile the program and test it for all conditions 
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Conditions
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a whole number");
int num1=scan.nextInt();
int num2=scan.nextInt();
int num3=scan.nextInt();
int num4=scan.nextInt();
if((num1>=10)||(num1<20))||(num1>=0)||(num1<10)||(num1==-1)||(num1>20);
System.out.println(Math.pow(10,num1));
System.out.println(100*num1);
System.out.println("Your entry is invalid");
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Why don't you tell us what output you expect and what output you are getting?

Comment: [**Read up on the basics**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Comment: what I am trying to do is if you input a number from 0-9 you'll get the number you inputted times 100. if you input a number from 10-19 you'll get the result of 10 raised to the power of the number you inputted. If you input a number that is larger than 20 you'll get a message stating that the number is invalid. Also, if you input a -1 the program will not provide an output and the program will exit. I get an error message from the compiler in line 12. it states that there is an illegal start of an expression and that it is not an expression.

Comment: You really should at least spend some time formatting your question. It's incredibly hard to read.

Comment: Check your `;` and your brackets `()`. I'm voting to close as typos.

Comment: my program finally compiled. Thank you Sotirios! It was a bracket typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you are asking how to do if statements? That would be the best way to handle these conditions. In your project description, you say if the user enters a number in the range 10 <= x < 20, then do an if statement doing exactly that.

```
if(num1 >= 10 && num1 < 20) {
    //do your 10^num1 stuff 
}
else if(num1 >= 0 && num1 < 10 ) {
    //do the num * 100 stuff
}
else if(num1 > 20){
    //number is > 20. Handle this however you have to.
}
else {
    //num is in the negatives. Exit
}
```